# Rails: Multiple parameters before do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax

I have this syntax which works (since it's from the API, pretty much)

```
  <% form_tag :action => "whatever" do -%>
    <div><%= submit_tag 'Save' %></div>
  <% end -%>
```

and this, which works

```
<%=  form_tag({:action => "whatever"}, {:method => "get"})%>
```

Now I have tried to combine them, guessing the syntax. The "get" does not get added as the form method as I had hoped. How should this read?

```
  <% form_tag :action => "whatever",:method => "get"  do -%>
    <div><%= submit_tag 'Save' %></div>
  <% end -%>
```

Form tag should read:

```
<form action="hello/whatever" method="get"/>
```

not

```
<form action="hello/whatever?method=get" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<% form_tag({:action => 'whatever'}, :method => "get")  do -%>
      <div><%= submit_tag 'Save' %></div>
<% end -%>
```

Looking at the [API docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag), the issue is that `:method` needs to go in the `options` hash, and the `:action` in the `url_for_options` hash, and you need the extra curly brackets so the interpreter knows they are different hashes.

Comment: +1, with a method declaration with two = {} parameters, you must indicate when one hash ends and the other starts. {:action => 'whaterver'}, :method => "get" does that.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that the best way to do this is not use anonymous route names and use named routes. It's a lot better and cleaner that way e.g.

```
<% form_tag discussions_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <div><%= submit_tag 'Save' %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks cyx! I know how to do that now thanks to my own question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/474667

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
<% form_tag(:action => "whatever", :method => "get")  do -%>
    <div><%= submit_tag 'Save' %></div>
<% end -%>
```

`ri form_tag` gives you examples as well.

Comment: yeah. that puts the action attribute like this /hello/input002?method=get which is not the idea :)