# Where is this "posts_path" variable defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables

I'm following [this tutorial](http://guides.rails.info/getting_started_with_rails.html) (seems good) for Rails. After I run

```
ruby script/generate scaffold Post
```

then this link works in one of the erb files:

```
<%= link_to "My Blog", posts_path %>
```

**WHY?** I've looked for "posts_path" in the whole app and it's nowhere to be found. On the other hand, this

```
<%= link_to "My Blog", home_path %>
```

does **not** work, and it's also a Controller.

Where is the `posts_path` defined?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`posts_path` is a named route you get for free from the route that was added by `script/generate scaffold`.  See `routes.rb` you should see something like this:

```
map.resources :posts
```

See the [API docs for information on what other named routes you get](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Resources.html) for free.

Also you can run `rake routes` and see what all your `routes.rb` is giving you.

If you want a home_path named route add a line like this to your `routes.rb`:

```
map.home '/home', :controller => "home", :action => "index"
```

Comment: Awesome! As you know, that worked. Still wondering why I need that huge line for "home" whereas I only need the map.resources for posts, but I imagine that it will all come clear soon...or after reading the API docs. Thanks again!

Comment: It's longer because it's departing from the RESTful routes conventions.  You could do: map.resource :home

Note the non-plural resource.  That would give you a home_path named route that went to that controller, but you would be stuck with /home.  The other way, you can specify whatever you want.

Comment: Cool. I think your last line, corrected, is map.home '/home', :controller => "home", :action => "index"... because otherwise Rails wants to use HomeControllerController... THANKS again.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that "posts_path" is created dynamically by Rails at runtime.  Look at your routes.rb file - Home is probably not defined the same way as Posts.  It has nothing to do with you controllers, it's dependent on the route definition.

Answer (score 1):

`map.root :controller => "home"` would be a shorter way of writing the path to your home directory. This will use / has the home, and not /home. If you still want to use /home (and home_path), `map.home 'home', :controller => "home"` will do the same thing.

There's a [great guide written by Mike Gunderloy](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing_outside_in.html) about everything there is to know about routing.

Comment: Awesome, the tutorial already covered the map.root, but I still don't understand the LONG syntax for map.home and the short syntax for map.root, but perhaps if I read the guide you suggested I'll get there. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: map.root tells your application what to do when the route "/" (the index) is requested. map.home on the other hand defines a new route '/home' and then you must specify the route name (since it uses method_missing to generate it) and then the controller. map.root is so much better for that.